# Decoding failed: Syntax error Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, syntax, error-handling, decoding

Hi I have use a magento wordpress single sigin plugin , for this in installation it is suggested to add this code in magento index file .

// for wordpress login

```
$adminwp = "/var/www/projects/magentowoo/index.php/admin";
$wploadwp = "/var/www/projects/arun/rohitgoel/wp-load.php";
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//echo $uri;


if(!strpos($uri, $adminwp) && !strpos($uri, 'downloader')) {
    require_once($wploadwp); 

}
```

it works fine but it  a strange issue, when i am adding the product image in admin it gives a error

> Decoding failed: Syntax error

i have try to comment out this code and than image works properly. Please suggest how can i fix this

Comment: This is most probably be json decode error.

Answer (score 0):

Update your browser Flash version, if Flash is being blocked by the browser as being outdated this error will occur on the website.